# How to rotate a simple model if you have accelerator, gyroscope, magnetometer data?

Tags: python, modeling, import

I have accelerator, gyroscope, and magnetometer data in an excel spreadsheet right now - is there anyway to update the position of the model with this information?

I can turn this data into Euler angles (roll, pitch, yaw) as well.

[[image: Sensor Data & Euler Conversion]

[[image: Sensor Data & Euler Conversion]

```
0.09692 0.039491 -0.069455
0.10186 0.040769 -0.073018
0.10803 0.043278 -0.077164
0.11481 0.045181 -0.081301
0.12036 0.047688 -0.085457
0.12653 0.048973 -0.088998
0.13269 0.051484 -0.093142
0.13885 0.05277 -0.096683
0.14441 0.05467 -0.10084
0.14996 0.056563 -0.10439
0.15614 0.059082 -0.10914
0.16108 0.06159 -0.11331
0.16541 0.064088 -0.11687
0.17095 0.065983 -0.12042
0.1759  0.067882 -0.12459
0.18146 0.069784 -0.12875
0.18702 0.072303 -0.13351
0.19257 0.074809 -0.13705
0.19812 0.077322 -0.14121
0.20429 0.079845 -0.14596
0.20984 0.080516 -0.1489
0.21537 0.082406 -0.15184
0.22033 0.084925 -0.15661
0.22587 0.087433 -0.16015
0.23143 0.090565 -0.16491
0.23698 0.092471 -0.16906
0.24252 0.095589 -0.1726
0.24745 0.096869 -0.17555
0.25423 0.10001 -0.18029
0.26039 0.10375 -0.18442
0.26594 0.10627 -0.18856
0.2721  0.1094  -0.1927
0.27703 0.1119  -0.19625
0.2838  0.11504 -0.20037
0.28935 0.11695 -0.20452
0.29489 0.11945 -0.20745
0.30043 0.12135 -0.211
0.3066  0.12266 -0.21514
0.31215 0.12396 -0.2193
0.31707 0.12523 -0.22164
0.32199 0.12713 -0.22458
0.32753 0.12964 -0.22812
0.33368 0.13216 -0.23165
0.33862 0.13406 -0.2352
0.34417 0.13658 -0.23935
0.3491  0.13788 -0.24291
0.35528 0.13981 -0.24827
0.35959 0.14231 -0.25121
0.36573 0.14666 -0.25472
0.37129 0.14981 -0.25947
0.37684 0.15356 -0.26421
0.383   0.15732 -0.26895
0.3892  0.15927 -0.27552
0.39564 0.16147 -0.29734
0.40146 0.16365 -0.35821
0.40711 0.16567 -0.44775
0.41276 0.17016 -0.53849
0.41838 0.17402 -0.6274
0.42294 0.17745 -0.72731
0.42901 0.1812  -0.84672
0.43432 0.18607 -0.99723
0.43932 0.19251 -1.1691
0.44436 0.19903 -1.3452
0.44957 0.20578 -1.5341
0.45545 0.21203 -1.7285
0.46273 0.21914 -1.9363
0.4694  0.23062 -2.1489
0.47613 0.24224 -2.3683
0.48115 0.24915 -2.5968
0.48845 0.26086 -2.8186
0.49583 0.27767 -3.0519
0.50437 0.30436 -3.2905
0.51219 0.32678 -3.5274
0.51942 0.34508 -3.7704
0.52771 0.36452 -4.0073
0.52123 0.30253 -4.296
0.52421 0.30086 -4.6168
0.52835 0.30818 -5.0308
0.53244 0.31553 -5.4448
0.53733 0.32572 -5.8795
0.5419  0.3356  -6.2946
0.54674 0.34575 -6.6891
```

#### Edit:

I am still having an issue. It seems that the rotation matrix is not functioning properly. I attached a picture above. If I type in 45 degrees into the X degree slot in the picture, the object will move 45 degrees. But if I force 45 degrees into the text editor and make that an input to the rotational matrix, the object moves at an noticeably larger angle than 45 degrees.

[image: Rotation Matrix]

Comment: This will probably need a python script

Comment: Can you post a .csv file of some of the data?

Comment: Im not exactly sure how to post csv files on here - anyway I could email the files to you?

Comment: @ScottMilner See above

Comment: @ScottMilner I also added pictures of the data files.

Comment: Copy/paste it, then select the text and hit the codes sample formatting button...

Comment: @Joey I agree with JakeD, it would be a lot easier to help you with text than with images. Also, how do you want the magnetometer data to move the object?

Comment: @ScottMilner Okay, I added the first 40 lines of the Euler angle conversions from the sensor data. This is the data that will be necessary to see the simple model pivot on a point in my opinion. Do you believe you could help me?

Comment: @ScottMilner This link is essentially what I need but not real time...                        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Tjm3lMp4Co

Comment: @ScottMilner are you in scripting mode/ animation mode/ or another mode?

Comment: @ScottMilner Thanks a lot for the help. I am still having an issue. It seems that the rotation matrix is not functioning properly. I attached a picture above. If I type in 45 degrees into the X degree slot in the picture, the object will move 45 degrees. But if I force 45 degrees into the text editor and make that an input to the rotational matrix, the object moves at an noticeably larger angle than 45 degrees  . Any suggestions?

Comment: @Joey You need to have your angle in radians, not degrees.

Comment: @Joey I've added code to convert the angles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the Accelerometer and Magnetometer data, but the rotation can be done pretty easily with **[Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)**.

After installing **Animation Nodes** (link above), create a text block in Blender with all of your Euler Rotation data. Make sure that there is only one space between each of the elements so it can be parsed easier:

[image]

In the **Animation Nodes** node editor add a *Text Block Reader* node (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to search all nodes or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to view the node menu). Then add a *Split Text* node and split by *Lines*:

[image]

Next, we need to parse all of these strings into vectors. To do this, add an *Expression* node and create a new input from the Text List output of the previous node and name it `t`. Use the gear icon to set the output type to *Euler List*. Paste the following code into the text box:

```
[[float(e) for e in a.split(" ")] for a in t]
```

If your data is in degrees, you'll need to convert to radians:

```
[[(float(e)*pi/180) for e in a.split(" ")] for a in t]
```

[image]

The rest of it is just inserting and connecting nodes. Here's the completed NodeTree:

[image]

You can replace the `Cube` object with whatever yours is named.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Are you in scripting/ animation/ other mode? @ScottMilner

Comment: @Joey I'm in the Animation Nodes node editor. You have to install the addon to see it.

Comment: This is great! I hadn't heard about Animation Nodes, will give it a try!